# Swapping the month and the year in a 4 digit date string

Tags: c#, datetime, date-formatting

Basically, I am accepting an expiration date. Let's say 12/24. The API I am submitting it to is very specific, no slash, and the year has to be first.

Removing the slash is easy:

```
var dt = Convert.ToString(payment.ExpirationDate.Replace("/", string.Empty));
```

So, now I have a 4 digit number in a string, I suppose I could `Convert.ToInt32` as well and have an int.

But either way, I am not sure how to split and swap. With the string, it wants a character, not a number.

Comment: try splitting the string by `/`, then you'll have an array you can call `Reverse` on to reorder it. If it still has to be a string, you can join the array back with a `/` or whatever. What is the exact format that the api requires?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. **What have you tried?** What part of this do you need help with? There is a wealth of information in the language documentation and any number of tutorials that explain how to manipulate strings. Please post the code you've written to solve the problem, explain what that code does, what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("12/24", "MM/yy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("yyMM"));`

Comment: I would not use a DateTime if you currently have a string. You could hit parsing issues. E.g., defaults are if the year is 49 or less, it's the current century. 50 or higher would be the last century. You also have the issue of time zones and offsets (admittedly, should have no affect if all you have are month and year). Dates are much easier to program against as strings unless you to manipulate them (adding days, converting offsets, etc.).

Comment: @ps2goat Added a way to avoid to two-digit problem in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're dealing with dates, you should probably use `DateTime`. This allows you to verify the date and generate any other formats you desire.

Something like this should do the job:

```cs
string input = "12/24";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "MM/yy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
string output = date.ToString("yyMM");
```

Use the above if you're certain the date has the correct format. If not, you could verify it using:

```
bool isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "MM/yy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
                                      DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime date);
if (isValid)
{
    string output = date.ToString("yyMM");
    //...
}
else { /* Do something about it */ }
```

To avoid mistaking the century for years 50 or above ([as addressed in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2084315/ps2goat)), you could create a custom CultureInfo and change the `TwoDigitYearMax` property:

```
CultureInfo myCultureInfo = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID);
myCultureInfo.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = 2099;
```

Then, you pass `myCultureInfo` instead of `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` to `ParseExact()` or `TryParseExact()`.

Answer (score 0):

After Removing the slash

```
public static string ReverseString(this string s)
{
    char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(arr);
    return new string(arr);
}
```

Example :

```
var dt = Convert.ToString(payment.ExpirationDate.Replace("/", string.Empty));
var dt2 = dt.ReverseString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your original string to a `DateTime` object using [`ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netcore-3.1):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(payment.ExpirationDate, "MM/yy", null)
```

And with that, formatting a `DateTime` object as "yyMM" is quite easy:

```
datetime.ToString("yyMM")
```

So a full example using the string you've provided:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("12/24", "MM/yy", null).ToString("yyMM"));
```

Gives the output as:

```
2412
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a regular expression to extract year + month from the input string in two separate variables. Then you can reorder/format them whatever you want.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var regexTest = new Regex(@"(?<month>\d{2})/(?<year>\d{2})");
        var input = "12/24";
        var match = regexTest.Match(input);
        if(match.Success) {
            var monthValue = match.Groups["month"];
            var yearValue = match.Groups["year"];
            Console.WriteLine($"{yearValue} - {monthValue}");
        }
    }
}
```